# Why is TcpListener never accepting the TcpClient?

Tags: c#, tcp, tcplistener

I have a device that acts as a TcpClient and sends TCP packets to a set IP on my network.

When I run the standard TcpListener program (from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=net-6.0)), it gets stuck in the `server.AcceptTcpClient()` instruction, never being able to actually detect the connection.

I have used Wireshark to check if the packets were actually being sent, and they are.

I have checked that packets are TCP and that the SYN is being sent. They are marked as duplicate ports since they are never accepted by the host.

This is my code (copied and slightly modified from the MS documentation above).

```
public static class Connection
    {
        public static void Connect(int port)
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                server = new(localAddress, port);

                // Start listening for clients
                server.Start();

                // Listening loop
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");

                    // Wait for client to connect
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient(); // NEVER UNBLOCKS

                    // Close connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket exception: ", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for clients
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "not for standard packets"? TcpClient, TcpListener, etc. works for TCP/IP. 
Are you sure the device is using TCP? Perhaps it's using UDP? Are they some other transport layer protocol? Do you have something already listening on port 13000 and you're ignoring the error? Can we see documentation for the controller and also your code?

Comment: TCP is a streaming oriented protocol, i.e. it creates a connection, transfers some data, and closes the connection. If something just want to throw out packets, without first setting up a connection, it would use UDP. So, in wireshark, do you see the SYN/ACK packets for setting up a connection? Or are the packets really UDP?

Comment: TCP for every packet get an ack.  If the ack does not occurred the packet gets resent up to 3 times at 5 seconds intervals.  Also in wireshark you will see [FIN] if the connection closes.  You can check the ACKS by looking at the sequence number of the sent packet and the received packet.  When I use wireshark I normally filter so I'm only seeing the source and destination IP.  If packets are not being received the connection is probably closing, the port is being used by another app, or a virus checker (firewall) is blocking the port number.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wireshark, but it seems like the port number is 62000. Why are you listening on 13000?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I am actually listening to the correct port when I call the method, 13000 was just the example since the MS documentation uses that port. The IP in the question is not my IP either.

Comment: I see. Well, by specifying an IP address to listen to, you're binding to that IP address. Is the IP address you're specifying the same one as the client is trying to connect to?

Comment: If you have not done so already, check the firewall, that is most likely blocking incoming connections on random ports.

Comment: You are listening on `127.0.0.1` which is only for the loopback. Instead listen on `IPAddress.Any`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you, this solved it. I thought specifying my localhost address would bind it to the interface, not to the address itself. Post an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind to the outgoing network adapter, rather than the loopback, use `IPAddress.Any`

```cs
server = new(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

You are also mising `using` in various place, and ideally you should use `async`. There also efficiencies you can make with reusing the same buffer.

```cs
public static async Task Connect(int port)
{
    TcpListener server = null;
    try
    {
        server = new(IPAddress.Any, port);

        // Empezar a escuchar peticiones de clientes
        server.Start();

        // Buffer para leer datos
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[256];
        string data = "";

        // Entrar al bucle de escucha
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Esperando conexión...");

            // Bloquear el programa hasta aceptar una petición
            using TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Conectado!");
            data = "";

            // Crear una trama para leer y escribir
            using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            int i;

            // Recibir todos los datos del cliente
            while ((i = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine($"Recibido: {data}");

                // Procesar los datos enviados por el cliente
                data = data.ToUpper();
                i = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data, 0, data.Length, buffer, 0);

                // Enviar una respuesta
                await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine($"Devuelto: {data}");
            }

            // Terminar la conexión
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Socket exception: ", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Dejar de escuchar clientes
        if(server?.Active)
            server.Stop();
    }
}
```

Note that the above code will only deal with one client at a time. If you want to deal with multiple, you need to hand off the `TcpClient` to a `Task.Run` task.